# Getting "invalid load key" when using pickle.loads() on a object serialized into string

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pickle, python-3.6

I used `pickle.dumps(obj)` to store a serialized object in my PostgreSQL database (I know this is not a great practice - I am in a hurry). To retrieve this pickled object I did the following using sqlalchemy:

```
result = sql_engine.execute("SELECT object FROM schema.table WHERE condition")
pickled_object = result.fetchone()[0] #getting one element from one row
obj = pickle.loads(pickled_object.encode(),
                      encoding="I've tried a bunch of different encodings")
```

I wrote a script to try `pickle.loads()` with every different encoding built-in to python, but I always get the same error: `_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x5c'.`

`\x5c` is ascii for `\` (which I can see at the start of the string I'm trying to unpickle), so I've tried removing this first character (thinking maybe it's some artifact due to SQL), but then I just get the same error with the second character of my string (I have even tried removing the second character, and I get the same error with the third).

For anyone who might know a lot about encoding here is the start of my string both raw and encoded:

```
pickled_object[:20] = '\\x800363736f6c617273'
pickled_object.encode()[:20] = b'\\x800363736f6c617273' #duh.
```

This might also be worth noting:

```
In[170]: chardet.detect(pickled_object.encode())
Out[170]: {'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii', 'language': ''}
```

The similar questions I have seen on SO were all to do with `pickle.load()`, not `pickle.loads()`. SQL is new to me, and I know nothing about encoding - so this might be a very basic misunderstanding. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: The start of the pickle string identifies the protocol used in the pickling. For protocol 3, my pickling starts with b'\x80\x03'. And for protocol 4 b' \x80\x04'. And most of the string consists of hex bytes of the form \xcc.

Comment: The \\ is a clue. It suggests double encoding. It means that you have a literal \ in your string, but you're only supposed to have binary, so the \ is used to escape non-ASCII bytes. You've probably inserted a `bytes` object into a `varchar` column. Try doing `SELECT decode(object, 'escape') FROM ...` and see what you get back.